# How can I iterate over the test data using webdriverio with mocha?

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io

I have a JSON based test data, how can I iterate over this test data for the test to run for each cred object?

```
cred: {
        nameValue: 'ant',
        emailValue: 'ant@gmail.com',
        passwordValue: 'ant',
    },
cred: {
        nameValue: 'bat',
        emailValue: 'bat@gmail.com',
        passwordValue: 'bat',
     },
```

Answer (score 1):

your test data JSON file should be like this,

```
[
       {
        "nameValue": "ant",
        "emailValue": "ant@gmail.com",
        "passwordValue": "ant"
    },
     {
        "nameValue": "bat",
        "emailValue": "bat@gmail.com",
        "passwordValue": "bat"
     } 
]
```

Now you can access them by index ( as in an array )

```
        const testDataObject = require("path to testData json");

             // to loop on all elements
             testDataObject.forEach(function(element) {
                it(' test case  def ', function() {
                     console.log("nameValue "+ element['nameValue']+ "emailValue 
             "+element['emailValue'] + "passwordValue "+element[passwordValue]); 
                });
            });

          // to select any particular index
         it(' test case  def ', function() {
                 console.log("nameValue "+ testDataObject[1]['nameValue']+ "emailValue 
  "+testDataObject[1]['emailValue'] + "passwordValue "+testDataObject[1][passwordValue]); 
            });
        });
```

And name your testData file name as Credentials_Valid.json ( best practice )

or
you can do in this way

```
    {
    "cred1":
    {
       "nameValue": "ant",
        "emailValue": "ant@gmail.com",
        "passwordValue": "ant",
    },
    "cred2":
    {
        "nameValue": "bat",
        "emailValue": "bat@gmail.com",
        "passwordValue": "bat",
    }     
}
```

and access the test data in nodejs code by

```
console.log( `${testDataObject['cred1']["nameValue"]}` );
console.log( `${testDataObject['cred1']["emailValue"]}` );
console.log( `${testDataObject['cred1']["passwordValue"]}` );
```